# MGWT and GWT- RPC

Tags: cordova, mgwt

I don't understand how to implement mgwt client with gwt rpc service. I have gone through these blogs too.

http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html
http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-requestfactory-and-phonegap.html

But still not helpful to proceed. Anyone please point any sample for this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find this post useful:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgwt/8WOo00f_L2A

Anyway, if you can use other mechanism for communication client-server I'd suggest you REST-JSON taking advantage of [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) ([official doc here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests)). I used it, and it worked without problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through a lot of forums, looking for the correct steps. Actually now I am able to resolve this gwt-rpc communication. Server gets a HIT, this mobile client notified. I am not using JSON so far.

Comment: @Sandip How did you solved the gwt-rpc communication? Can you explain it in more detail? e.g. posting sample code? The example project from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgwt/8WOo00f_L2A is not downloadable any more.

Comment: I don't have sample code. I can help you. I hope you have a gwt project with remote service. project.gwt.xml must have this.                                                     <inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT"/>
  <inherits name='com.googlecode.gwtphonegap.PhoneGap' />

Comment: public static RemoteServiceAsync createPhoneGapService() {

  RemoteServiceAsync service = GWT.create(RemoteService.class);
  ServiceDefTarget servDefTarget = (ServiceDefTarget)service;
  
  PhonegapUtil.prepareService(servDefTarget, url, servletname);

  return service;
 }

Comment: @marian-lux The URL is important as you have to enter your server host path with url pattern. That varies with your application deployment. You can make trial and error to get the server hit.

Comment: MarianLux @Sandip, feel free to modify my answer, if think your response add value to it :).